# String inside ion-select doesn't change unless it's clicked

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, events

What I am trying to achieve is when I trigger my method `"onUpdateMeasure($event)"` to update my `{{unit}}` automatically. With what I've done, partially works, it updates the `{{unit}}` value but only if you click the select (the one with the placeholder "`placeholder="My Goal"`". What I want to achieve is when I click the first select and trigger `"onUpdateMeasure($event)"` to update `{{unit}}` on the second ion-select automatically, not only when I click on it. If you guys have any idea I would really appreciate it

HTML

```
  <ion-select
      [interfaceOptions]="customInterfaceOptions"
      interface="action-sheet"
      formControlName="measure"
      (ionChange)="onUpdateMeasure($event)"
        <ion-select-option value="k">k</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="l">l</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>

  <ion-select
      [interfaceOptions]="customInterfaceOptions"
      interface="action-sheet"
      formControlName="unit"
      placeholder="My Goal">
      <ion-select-option value="l02">{{unit}} per week</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="l1"> {{unit}} per week </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
```

TS

```
    onUpdateMeasure(e) {
       let selection = e.detail.value;
       if (selectiont === "k") {
         this.unit = "kg";
       } else if (selectionWeight == "l") {
         this.unit = "lbs";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Updated your code and I hope this will work for you.

HTML

```
<ion-select [interfaceOptions]="customInterfaceOptions"
  interface="action-sheet" (ionChange)="onUpdateMeasure($event)">
 <ion-select-option value="k">k</ion-select-option>
 <ion-select-option value="l">l</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>

<ion-select [interfaceOptions]="customInterfaceOptions"
  interface="action-sheet"  placeholder="My Goal" [(ngModel)]='unit'>
 <ion-select-option  [value]='unit'>{{unit}} per week</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

TS

```
onUpdateMeasure(e) {
 let selection = e.detail.value;
 if (selection === "k") {
   this.unit = "kg";
 } 
 else if (selection == "l") {
   this.unit = "lbs";
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I can't use [(ngModel)] as i am using reactive forms and I have a form control on each...Is there a way maybe using both?

Comment: I was thinking to add "[selectedText]="editProfileForm.controls.weeklyLossFrequency.value" in ion-select but it takes the value I wrote as a string and not the next between "ion-select-option"

Comment: Can you post your code in which you have used form control. Maybe i can help after seeing full code.